# Fedora 33 OpenVPN DNF Leak with "systemd-resolved"

Tags: fedora, dns, openvpn, systemd-resolved

I upgraded from Fedora 32 to 33. Apparently 33 changes the default DNS resolver. The result is that attempting to use an OpenVPN connection leaves DNS Leaks.

I'm using PIA as the vpn.

My ".ovpn" additions of:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/client.up
down /etc/openvpn/client.down
```

which worked in Fedora 32 no longer work in 33.

I've been googling like mad but so far have been unsuccessful.

I'm looking for a shell script setup for the call to openvpn, or modifications to the ".ovpn" file, or both. Or a GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much angst, I have a working solution.

Starting with [Fedora WIKI OpenVPN](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/OpenVPN?rd=Openvpn) as a baseline, I found a number of gotcha's and not quite rights.

Modifying their directions to ***my specifics*** leads to:

```
INSTALL "easy-rsa"
```

located in /usr/share/easy-rsa/3.0.8/easyrsa  *** NOT /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa

```
cd /usr/share/easy-rsa/3.0.8

sudo ./easyrsa init-pki
```

init-pki complete; you may now create a CA or requests.

Your newly created PKI dir is: /usr/share/easy-rsa/3.0.8/pki

```
sudo ./easyrsa build-ca
```

*** Use defaults except for password

Your new CA certificate file for publishing is at: /usr/share/easy-rsa/3.0.8/pki/ca.crt

```
sudo ./easyrsa build-client-full {Client-1}
```

(*** Expires in 825 days ***)

**### Start here for Passworded Clients not using a Certificate ###**

```
sudo cp [pia]/ca.rsa.4096.crt /etc/openvpn/.

sudo cp [pia]/crl.rsa.4096.pem /etc/openvpn/.

sudo cp [pia]/openvpn-strong-nextgen/{any}.ovpn /etc/openvpn/client/pia_udp.conf

sudo gedit /etc/openvpn/client/pia_udp.conf
```

Remove lines:  "*remote {bahamas}.privacy.network 1197*" and "*proto udp*". This is to make the config **generic**.

```
sudo chgrp -R openvpn /etc/openvpn/client
```

**At this point I went for the GUI:**

**Repeat this for each VPN connect**

### **Network (GUI)**

Select **+** to add a VPN

Select OpenVPN

**Name**            *NewJersey*

**Gateway**         *us-newjersey.privacy.network:1197:udp*

**Type**            *Password*

**Username**        *{PIA user name}*

**Password**        *{PIA password}*

**CA Certificate**  /etc/openvpn/pia-ca.rsa.4096.crt

***NOTE: Resolve permissions!***

Numerous permission issues! Watch (tail -f /var/log/messages) when starting GUI.

The **Network** GUI works. **No DNS Leaks**.

I also have a manual [Kill Switch](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/My+VPN+Linux+killswitch%3A+securely+disable+all+traffic+except+through+VPN+tunnel) that works well. It uses **ufw** (uncomplicated firewall) which must be installed. The script needs to be edited to replace all */usr/bin/ufw* with **/usr/sbin/ufw**.

**killswitch -e** to enable after establishing the VPN. Terminating or otherwise dropping the VPN connect will result in no connections at all until **killswitch -d** disables the kill switch and reconnects normally.

I've not yet managed to integrate the kill switch into the OpenVPN client to make it automatic.

In retrospect, I probably didn't need the client certificate.